# JavaScript Syntax Error (Calendar.js)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, view, syntax

[Updated Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnqX3.png)i am trying to pass database data from controller to calendar.js 's java script defines. But i am getting that errors while i am trying to do that. Can anybody help me about get rid of the syntax errors.

[image]

```
$(window).load(function() {
    var date = new Date(),
        d = date.getDate(),
        m = date.getMonth(),
        y = date.getFullYear(),
        started,
        categoryClass;

    var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        select: function(start, end, allDay) {
            $('#fc_create').click();

            started = start;
            ended = end;

            $(".antosubmit").on("click", function() {
                var title = $("#title").val();
                if (end) {
                    ended = end;
                }

                categoryClass = $("#event_type").val();

                if (title) {
                    calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent', {
                            title: title,
                            start: started,
                            end: end,
                            allDay: allDay
                        },
                        true // make the event "stick"
                    );
                }

                $('#title').val('');

                calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');

                $('.antoclose').click();

                return false;
            });
        },

        eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
            $('#fc_edit').click();
            $('#title2').val(calEvent.title);

            categoryClass = $("#event_type").val();

            $(".antosubmit2").on("click", function() {
                calEvent.title = $("#title2").val();

                calendar.fullCalendar('updateEvent', calEvent);
                $('.antoclose2').click();
            });

            calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
        },

        editable: true,

        var events = [];

        @foreach(var place in Model) {

            < text >

                var takvim = {
                    title: '@place.Ekip_id',
                    start: new Date(y, m, 28),
                    end: new Date(y, m, 29),
                };

            events.push(takvim);

            < /text>
        };
    });
});
```

Comment: Check the source of the page in the browser (or the error in the console) and you should see the problem.

Comment: When you checked your console, what line in your code is breaking? - I don't see images, where I'm at sorry if it is in the image.

Comment: var events = [];  ------------> there are 2 errors on this section , for events i am getting Expected  ':' error also on last line (i mean for  ' }); ' ) i am getting Syntax Error error.

Comment: i just added the detail error list picture to the my question.

Comment: @IbrahimSefaTuna The `var` keyword is not necessary as you are inside an object.